# What is $'\0' in bash?

Tags: bash

What does this [`$'\0'`](https://github.com/hmaverickadams/breach-parse/blob/84c59a431917f5d9a3ec573e23086dc2f3a337b3/breach-parse.sh#L69) mean in the `-d` option for the `read` command?

I understand it is being used as a delimiter for the `read` command, but I'm lost with the syntax used.

```
find path/to -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do
        grep "Willy" "$file"
done
```

Comment: `read -d $'\0'` is not commonly used, people prefer `read -d ''`

Answer (score 4):

Turns out it is a nice trick to use `find` and `read` together to search through several files.

The `$'\0'` is the null character, and if the `find` [command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) is used with the `-print0` option, its results will be separated by the null character.

It is well explained [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/read.htm#examples).

Comment: There also exists a trick with the POSIX `find` to read accurately every filepath, whatever characters they're composed of